# How to check if a file's content is filled with white spaces/nulls/0s?

Tags: c#, .net

So currently I'm coding a file scanner with signature checking. But I have a problem, there are files that are detected by infected by the program but they are protected operating system files. So I took a look at the two files' contents, and they were the same.

In Sublime Text, they were **filled with zeros**, like a binary file but only with zeros.

In Notepad++, they were **filled with NULs**.

And in classic Notepad, I just saw white spaces.

So I've tried multiple solutions, the first was to check if the file was null or filled with white spaces with the following code :

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text)))
                    MessageBox.Show("yes");
```

Assuming TextBox1.Text is the file path. Sadly, that code didn't work. So I've tried but with IsNullOrEmpty :

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text)))
                    MessageBox.Show("yes");
```

But still the same result. Finally, since the files' content were technically **null**, I've decided to check if they were null with the following code :

```
if (File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text) == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("yes");
```

But that also didn't work.

Is there a solution to this problem or do I have to **skip protected operating system files**?

Comment: The content of a file will not change by only viewing it. But each application can use different **presentation strategies** to present the file content. Actually you describe that different presentations but you did not say anything about the real content. We can only **guess** the file contains only 0x00 bytes

Comment: I don't know the real content. I used 3 different text editors, and my guess is that they are just white spaces or null. I didn't say that it will change by viewing it, however, it's difficult to get its real content if both 3 text editors have different presentations. How can I get its real content then?

Comment: Do not use a text editor - use a hex viewer ;o)

Comment: A 0-byte will be represented as NUL in Notepad++. "classic" Notepad isn't that good in displaying files that don't contain "Windows Text". Whitespace is spaces, tabs, newlines - not NULLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll get a good result with using strings, you should read bytes instead:

```
byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(...);

if(ba.All(b => b == 0))
  //file is all zero filled
```

Beware naively reading all bytes from a file into memory; plenty of files on the users drive may exceed the maximum size a .net object may be (or easily exceed the memory installer in the machine). Consider reading them gradually with a stream instead; the logic for a binary file could be to read it until you hit a non zero byte. If you reach the end o the file without finding one, it was all zero

you didn't say what else you're doing with your files so it's hard to advise

Comment: Yes, I used this method before, it works just fine :)